# Specifying multiple types for the same field in OpenAPI specs

Tags: swagger, openapi

I am looking to represent the following JSON Object in OpenAPI:

```
 {
   "name": "filter name",
   "type": "type of filter",
   "depends_on": "parent filter",

    // the value can be :
   "values": ["value 1", "value 2", ...]   

   // or
   "value": {
      "parent 1" : ["value 1", "value 2", ...],
      "parent 2": [ "value 3", "value 4", ...],
      ..... 
    }
 }
```

I have tried to use the following spec

```
Filters:
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        type:
          type: string
        depends_on:
          type: string
        values:
          type: object
          additionalProperties:
            oneOf:
              - integer
              - string
```

but it didn't work as expected.

Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Solved using `oneOf`:
I found the solution [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/401)

```
    Filters:
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        type:
          type: string
        depends_on:
          type: string
        values:
          oneOf:
            - type: object
              properties:
                parent value:
                  type: array
                  items:
                    type: string
                    example: "value 1"
            - type: array
              items:
                type: string
```